# заменить outerHTML или innerHTML у элемента так чтобы события не отвалились

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста как в HTML заменить outerHTML или innerHTML у элемента чтобы события не отвалились. Возможно ли это? Есть таблица мне нужно поменять ее код, я заменяю outerHTML, она отображается как надо, но при этом все события отваливаются и таблица становится нерабочей.

Comment: Использовать методы для работы с DOM (createElement, appendChild и т.п.) а не это варварство

Comment: По факту при этих методах слушателей событий нужно добавлять заново либо можно пойти на родительскую ноду и сделать делегирование событий. Маленький рабочий пример вашего кода не помешал бы.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте ваш код, как вы это делаете сейчас, что было более понятно, в чем именно проблема